# Is it possible to reference different NuGet package versions in a Visual Studio solution?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

We are a team composed of 7 members and we want to create a Cloud Application (Windows Azure) with Visual Studio. Our application is hosted on GitHub so we have choose to use NuGet packages to keep our repository light as possible.

However two different projects in our Visual Studio solution need reference either Newtonsoft.Json version 4.0.2 or Newtonsoft.Json version 4.5.11.

We have tried to reference the right version for each project but we get this errors on build:

1. The type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
2. Cannot implicitly convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'

The second error suggests that there are conflicts between the two versions even if no project in our solution references the two version at the same time.

Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Thanks.

PS: Here are the most relevant information we have found about this issue.

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/known-issues

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=NuGet+multi+packages+version

Comment: How do you install the two different Newtonsoft.Json versions in your various projects? I would guess explicitly specifying both project name and package version, doing something like `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -ProjectName ProjectA -Version 4.0.2` and `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -ProjectName ProjectB -Version 4.5.11`, ought to do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while... Know that we have rewrite the piece of code which use the old reference to Newtonsoft.Json version 4.0.2.

Thanks.